# How to organize methods in a class?

Tags: python, oop

Let's consider a `Human` class. To implement it, the first approach would be to have one class including all the methods:

```
class Human:
   @property
   def height(self): 
      return self._height

   @property
   def weight(self): 
      return self._weight

   def LeftArm_Hand_Thumb_Bend(angle): 
      pass
```

This solution is simple but can be confusing especially if the amount of methods is very large.

A second approach separates the functions of a human body into sub-classes. These sub-classes are located in the same module and will be instantiated during the creation of the human object:

```
class Human:
   @property
   def height(self): 
      return self._height

   @property
   def weight(self): 
      return self._weight

   def __init__(self):
       self.arms = (
            __HumanArm(self),
            __HumanArm(self),
       )

class __HumanArm:
   def __init__(self):
       self.hand = __HumanHand(self)

...
```

This is slightly better than the first solution, but requires more complexity. Writing the human interface will be more boilerplate.

We can also think of a similar approach where the sub-classes are located inside the human class. This offers a better organisation although inner sub-classes are usually not recommended.

```
class Human:
   @property
   def height(self): 
      return self._height

   @property
   def weight(self): 
      return self._weight

   def __init__(self):
       self.arms = self.__Arms(self)

   class __Arms:
      def __init__(self):
          self.left = __Arm(self)

      class __Arm:
          def MoveThumb(): pass
...
```

To my opinion, the last solution is easier to use in an interactive terminal thanks to the auto-completion *i.e* IPython:

```
lucy = Human(name = 'Lucy')
lucy.arms.left.thumb.move()
```

As hierarchical collections are not really available in Python (dictionaries does not allow to use the `.` completion), I am trying to find a trick using classes.

So the question is how should I organize my Human class? I don't know if it is a good practice to use a local double underscore class that I instantiate in the constructor by passing the current instance to it.

I don't want to place the `Hand` class outside the `Human` class because this is a human hand and it is always attached to a body. Moreover it is not possible to instantiate a human hand without a living human body.

For those that requires a more specific application, let's simply think this human class is an interface that will be mainly use in a terminal to interact with a humanoid robot. Each method is more less linked to a low-level C function that communicate with the robot with Ethernet.

Considering this last paragraph, I would rather prefer this:

```
>>> bob = Humanoid(ip='192.168.68.2', port=3699)
>>> bob.PowerOn()
>>> bob.serial_number
4832927
>>> bob.arm<tab>
left right
>>> bob.arm.left.Move(30, speed=50)
>>> image = bob.eyes.left.GetImage()
```

Than this

```
>>> bob = Humanoid(ip='192.168.68.2', port=3699)
>>> bob.PowerOn()
>>> bob.serial_number
4832927
>>> bob_arm = bob.GetArm(0)    
>>> bob_arm.Move(30, speed=50)
>>> bob_left_eye = bob.GetEye(0)
>>> image = bob_left_eye.GetImage()
```

In conclusion, I am more focused on a `collection` of actions than a real object oriented architecture.

Comment: Firstly, note that `@property` only applies to the one method. Secondly, there is almost never a good reason to nest classes in Python, or to use `__leading_double_underscore` names. Thirdly, it's not clear why you think that `lucy.arms.left.thumb.move()` (*"ulgh"*, by the way...) is only possible with the last version, attributes don't require nested classes. *"it is not possible to instantiate a human hand without a living human body"* - challenge accepted...

Comment: @nowox> What is your purpose? A program is a tool, and you don't design a tool without knowing what you want to use it for.

Comment: This depends too much on what aspects of a human a `Human` is supposed to model and what kinds of interactions a `Human` is designed for.

Comment: @jonrsharpe "*challenge accepted*" what, you've never heard of an unbound method? :)

Comment: Surely that would be `lucy.arms['left'].hand.fingers['thumb'].move()`? The very fact that would mean a class in a class in a class in a class (before we even get to fingernails...), and given that [*"flat is better than nested"*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), suggests that you're barking up completely the wrong tree.

Comment: @spectras I updated my question with more details.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I initially thought about dictionaries. I feel it is much easier to have the auto-completion for the `left`, `right` than using a `key` that would require more characters.

Comment: There's yet another way not included: inheritance and mixins. This may or may not be applicable, but if it's a fantasy game you might have `class Human(Humanoid):` (Elf, Troll, Dwarf also inheriting from Humanoid), and `class Humanoid( Sentient, Biped, HasArms):` (contrast `class Centaur(Sentient, Quadruped, HasArms):` and `class Cow( Animal, Quadruped):` )

Comment: @jonrsharpe Nice article and this sentence applies to my question `Although practicality beats purity`.

Comment: @nowox not really, as it's impractical too

Comment: If you are just after auto completion in Ipython, maybe you should look into writing hooks that fix that for you in IPython. That way you could have a, in lack of better words, more sane code base for your humanoid class, and still have completion. As an example look at `h5py.enable_ipython_completer()` which allows tab-completion for HDF5 file paths.

Comment: I'm authentically interested in this conversation as an SE and an architect -- there are possibly methods here that can be analysed objectively. Classic SO, shutting it down out of hand: "not interesting to me-mod, therefore not interesting TO ANYONE EVER GETOUTOFMYKINGDEOMHEATHEN". Do I feel good about this? Very much not.